# Reproduce without using spread arguments (...) when passing arguments through to a function call

Tags: javascript

I have been learning about spread arguments and I found it rather surprising that when using: `cur.func.call(null, ...cur.arg, acc), args)` that if you have an empty array no argument is passed to `add()`.

Is it possible to reproduce this without using the `...` seen in this line of code `cur.func.call(null, ...cur.arg, acc), args)`

```js
class Lazy {
  constructor() {
    this.builtUpFuncs = [];
  }

  add(...newArgs) {
  console.info(newArgs)
    this.builtUpFuncs.push({
      func: newArgs[0],
      arg:  typeof newArgs[1] === "undefined"  ? [] : [newArgs[1]],
    });
    return this;
  }

  evaluate(target) {
          return target.map((args) => 
            this.builtUpFuncs.reduce((acc, cur) => 
                cur.func.call(null, ...cur.arg, acc), args)
        );
  }
}

const lazyClass = new Lazy();
    const returnValue =
      lazyClass
        .add(function timesTwo(a) { return a * 2; })
        .add(function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }, 1)
      .evaluate([1, 2, 3]);
      
      console.info(returnValue);
```

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the spread syntax, the traditional way is to use `apply` instead of `call`:

```
cur.func.apply(null, cur.arg.concat(acc))
```

Note that the `args` part is the second argument to `reduce`, not this function call.

In either syntax it is normal that if `cur.arg` is an empty array, the only argument passed is `acc`.

Comment: "Note that the args part is the second argument to reduce, not this function call." Ye, I realise its plopped down onto the lower line, that was me not returning and using `console` :) Otherwise, the last sentence is the key for me then.